# ASP.Net MVC - return view and launch document at same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a ASP.Net MVC form that upon submit I need a couple of things to happen.

- Firstly I need to generate a pdf report and launch it
- Secondly I need to return to the main index page

Currently I can do the first by returning a filestream from my action **OR** the second by returning a view but I can't figure out how to do both

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem here but I don't want my URL to be public so my visitors can download the PDF only when they fill in a form. Once they fill the form I want to push them the PDF and also return a Thank you message to the view. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you return the main index page first, and in the page have it make an ajax call to a separate action which returns the pdf file?

You would just need to make sure the ajax call opens up the response in a separate window/tab.

Comment: Unfortunately not allowed to rely on javascript so everything must be from post

Comment: I went with your solution in the end and added a link also in case no javascript. Thanks

Comment: How do you do the AJAX call that return the PDF?